# is PHP fopen() as APPEND better than file_get_(put)contents(), to avoid losing logs from multiple requests?

Tags: php, logging

Most examples I've seen to update text based log files seem to suggest checking that the file exists, if so load it into a big string with file_get_contents(), add your new logs onto it, and then writing it back with file_put_contents().

I may be over-thinking this, but I think I see two problems there. First, if the log file gets big, isn't it somewhat wasteful of the the scripts available memory to stuff the huge file contents into a variable? Second, it seems that if you did any processing between the 'get' and 'put', you risk the possibility that multiple site visitors may update between the two calls, resulting in lost log info.

So for a script that is simply called (GET or POST) and exited after doing some work, wouldn't it be better to just build up your current (shorter) log string to be written, and at then just before exit(), just open in APPEND mode and WRITE?

It would seem that either approach could lead to losing data if there were no LOCK on the file between get and put. In the case of file_get/put_contents, I see that method does have a flag available called "LOCK_EX", which I assume attempts to prevent that occurrence. But then there is that issue of the time taken to move a large file into an array, and add to it before writing back. Wouldn't it be better to use fopen (append) with some kind of 'lock', between the fopen() and the fwrite()?

I apologise as I *DO* understand that "best way to do something" questions are not appreciated by the community. But surely the is a preferred way that addresses the concerns I'm raising?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can also use `FILE_APPEND` option with `file_put_contents`. This is the simplest way and is safe against the race condition you describe.

Comment: If all the writers use `append` mode, everything should work fine. Any site that suggests reading and writing the whole file for a log file is simply wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you're not confusing this with something like JSON files? Those have to be read and written completely, because there's no way to append to JSON in place.

Comment: @Barmar No, sorry... this is plain old PHP, and I instinctively agree with your last point, for reasons i mentioned. But you'd be surprised how many examples show it just that way. Question: The 'manual' link for file_put_contents() does mention the FILE_APPEND flag, but it also mentions the LOCK_EX flag, which seems to address my concern. Should I combine both flags?

Comment: @Barmar - oh and the file is just plain text. Plain vanilla ASCII with CR/LF pairs ending each line.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about locking. The method used by `FILE_APPEND` should ensure that the data is written atomically.